# Sentry, output an object with more details?

Tags: python-3.x, sentry

Right now, when I have an exception, I can see a variable that is the instance of one of my class, but the output is :

```
obj : <utils.MyClass object at 0x7f55890a1670>
```

Is there a way to replace this at Sentry with a custom dict (the object is complex, so a **str** is not enough here).

Instead of this, I would have a dict showing the properties of my object.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

this can be easily done by overriding the **str** function

```
class Person:
   def __init__(self, _name, _age):
      self.name = _name
      self.age = _age
   def __str__(self):
       return f"{self.name} - {self.age}"
```

now if you created an object from Person and printed it, output will be as you specified in the **str** function

```
john - 37 # example of output
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was hoping to have more than a string being outputted : Having the underlying instances methods and their content, kind of like a dict that is being represented as a whole.

Comment: then all you have to do is instead of returning a string return  a dict.   
You can provide me with object example and desired output so i can help you